# remove grid column on shift+space in a wpf application

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-core

I have a simple wpf application where I want to remove one column and have the remaining (in column 2) fill the window when ctrl+space is pressed. I've looked into keybinding and commands, but I can't figure this one out.

**Code**:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="24" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="268" MinWidth="188" MaxWidth="346"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="64" Width="5"/>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Collections" FontFamily="Noto Sans" Foreground="#FF9B9B9B" FontSize="16" Name="TESTTEST" />
        <Button Content="Add" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,7,3,0" />
    </Grid>
    <StatusBar Grid.Row="1" Background="#FF151515" Foreground="#FF636363" BorderBrush="#FF1D1D1D"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: @mm8 static RouteCommand and KeyBinding on the window tag, but I can't figure out how to code the actual event to hide the column

Comment: Set the `Visibility`of all columns where `Grid.Column == 1` to `Collapsed`?

Comment: @mm8 yes, but how to I code the keybinding?

Comment: Where's the focus you press the key? Please provide an example of what you have actually tried. There are no key bindings in your current example.

Comment: Please share code of Key-binding. What you have tried. So I can figure it out